# div bg-2 should be same position as bg-1 even when scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scroll

Hi i am new to javascript, i wanted to do a scrolling show and hide for my 2 divs, however the one i did is currently when scroll it change to bg-2 already but the text is like cut. its not the exact same position as bg-1. Can i ask for help?

This is the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-estrela-zfkih7?file=/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100vh; height: 100vh;"></div>
    <div class="bg-1" id="bg-1">
      This is testing UI
    </div>

    <div class="bg-2" id="bg-2">
      This is another testing UI
    </div>
    <div class="bg-3">
      This is third testing UI
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<style>
  .bg-1 {
    height: 80vh;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
  }
  .bg-2 {
    display: none;
    height: 80vh;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
  }

  .bg-3 {
    height: 50vh;
    background: pink;
  }
</style>

<script>
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var elementTarget = document.getElementById("bg-1");

    var elementTargetRewards = document.getElementById("bg-2");

    console.log("window.scrollY", window.scrollY);
    console.log("elementTarget.offsetTop", elementTarget.offsetTop);

    console.log("rewards", elementTargetRewards.offsetTop);

    let lastScrollTop = 0;
    if (window.scrollY < elementTargetRewards.offsetTop - 100) {
      console.log("up 1");
      $("#bg-2").show();
      $("#bg-1").hide();
    } else if (window.scrollY < elementTarget.offsetTop) {
      console.log("up 1");
      $("#bg-1").show();
      $("#bg-2").hide();
    } else {
      // console.log('down 1');
      $("#bg-2").show();
      $("#bg-1").hide();
    }
    lastScrollTop = elementTarget.offsetTop;

    console.log("last", lastScrollTop);
  });
</script>
```

Desired output when scroll:

[image: desired output]

Comment: What do you want exactly, please ask a clear question, we are not be able to understand that.

Comment: when scrolling to the second div the "this another testing ui" word is cut. i wanted when scroll the word is not cut, something like fixed even when scroll the div will autochange

Comment: you want your second div in a fixed position, right?

Comment: do you want somwthing like bellow link?

https://www.nytimes.com/projects/2012/snow-fall/index.html#/?part=tunnel-creek

Comment: yess i want to be fixed but still can scroll

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('img_parallax.jpg');

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones. Increase the pixels if needed */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) {
  .parallax {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>In this example we have turned off parallax scrolling for mobile devices. It works as expected on all desktop screens sizes.</p>
<p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.</p>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

<div class="parallax"></div>

</body>
</html>
```